# EMC regulations versus electronics in the market

Tags: pcb, emc, regulations

I am wondering about starting low quantity sale of some of my products, that I've developed by myself. And there is a question - what are the regulations that I have to meet? Do I need to realize certified test in EMC lab? It is so expensive and because of that, in my low quantity "business" it will be impossible to perform it. How is it usually implemented? I dont believe in that every electronic board in the market has certification obtained in the way of EMC tests. How do they avoid it, what is the risk etc. My sale would be addressed to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

### UK, GB, Northern Ireland and the EU only

Specifically, you should concentrate on what regulations apply to you in terms of where you want to sell or ship stuff. In the UK it was an EU directive but, that has been replaced by [Electromagnetic Compatibility
Regulations 2016](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/950109/Guide-to-emc-regulations-2016-tp.pdf). There will be different regulations for different parts of the world of course.

So, in Europe and GB (Northern Ireland has a slightly different regulation now), it pretty much either follows the [EU directive](https://cemarking.net/eu-ce-marking-directives/emc-directive/) or the newer GB and [Northern Ireland](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/950110/Guide-to-emc-regulations-2016-northern-ireland-tp.pdf) regulations.

All of which allow/permit you to put certain stuff onto the market without testing to EMC standards (the term "standards" is used here whereas it is regulations that have to be legally met). But, you have to justify (in a technical document or file) why you feel it necessary not to conduct tests. So, hopefully, that answers this question: -

> *Do I need to realize certified test in EMC lab?*

Of course, if your product(s) is/are intentional radiators then you have to formally test at a certified test-house.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that, if the tests are carried out in a certified laboratory, the authorization will be the "most valid".

However, before (trying) to get the certification, I recommend doing the majority of the tests yourself (I did it myself as well) ... provided you have the right equipment ( spectrum analyzer, adequate antenna, LISN for conducted radiation, etc ...).

No need for an "anechoic chamber", do the tests in "free field" (on an embankment) in the true sense of the term. Just far enough away from any "reflective disruptor", buildings, cars ... :)